# Test Failed - Failed to set up the execution context to run the test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, global-variables, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am attempting to write unit tests for a set of classes that access or modify global variables.

The first global I needed to wrap up was:

```
extern std::atomic<Foo> GlobalFoo;
```

Where `Foo` is an `enum class`.  I wrote 2 separate classes to handle the setting and getting of the value.  I constructed unit tests that passed as expected.  Within the test files I include variables to copy the global state (plus extra stateless objects that I may use for testing).  I can then use these global copies for restoring values after each test.  For example:

```
namespace Tests
{
    // Global save state
    const Framework::Foo originalGlobal = Framework::GlobalFoo;

    // Test constants
    const auto service = Framework::FooRetriever();
    const auto testFoo = Framework::Foo::SomeValue;

    TEST_CLASS(FooRetrieverUnitTests)
    {

        ...
```

The next global I started working on was:

```
extern const std::unordered_map<
    std::vector<char>, std::vector<char>, std::hash<std::vector<char>> GlobalBar;
```

I want to construct a class that is going to return a shared pointer to this global collection.

I start off by writing my test constants:

```
namespace Tests
{
    // Alias
    using Collection = const std::unordered_map<
        std::vector<char>, std::vector<char>, std::hash<std::vector<char>>;

    // Global state
    const std::shared_ptr<Collection> global = 
        std::make_shared<Collection>(Framework::GlobalBar);

    TEST_CLASS(FooRetrieverUnitTests)
    {
        // TODO
    };
}
```

However, running the test at this point produced the following message **for all my tests** (i.e. not just this new test):

> Failed to set up the execution context to run the test

Commenting out the global allows all tests to run.

If I move the line commented as `// Global state` into a test method then the test will run without problem.

I looked into the error, but could not find anything that applied to my problem.  I suspect the error message is masking the real problem.  When I run the tests via command line I do not get any extra information.  I was led to believe that it was possibly due to a missing DLL (although I found this unlikely seeing as I was merely using the standard library with no extras).

My project is a static library, and my unit tests are in the form of a DLL (this is the default approach used by Microsoft Visual Studio's unit testing framework).

Minus the usual "don't use globals" rant (I need a handful of globals in this application, mainly concerning paths and language settings), I was wondering if anyone could provide some insight into the problem I am encountering.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong by making a copy of the global collection in my `Tests` namespace or there is another bug in Visual Studio's unit testing feature.

The code compiles without error or warnings but the unit tests will not run in this state.

Comment: did you solve it any way?